# How to run docker on ubuntu without the sudo

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I want to run my docker by running this command:

```
docker build -t getting-started .
```

I get the following error:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=getting-started&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

My question is: how can I run docker on ubuntu without adding "sudo"?

Comment: Thanks @BMitch for having found that duplicate! But it seems the answer I proposed here was not mentioned at all in the duplicate thread. Would you have some advice about this? (e.g., to cross-post my answer there? or just do nothing :)

Comment: @ErikMD if your answer applies there, then I'd post it there. I don't see an issue having a duplicate answer posted when only one of the questions is still open.

Comment: OK done, thanks @BMitch :)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Unlike what many tutorials on the web propose (add your user account to the `docker` group, which is risky! see below), you could just add an alias in your `.bashrc` to avoid typing `sudo`, while having the "password prompt protection".

**To be more precise:** the Docker daemon socket is owned by `root:docker`:

```sh
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 janv. 28 14:23 /var/run/docker.sock
```

so with this default setup, you need to prepend all docker CLI commands by `sudo`.

To avoid this, you can either:

1. Add `$USER` to the `docker` group (but that's quite risky to do this  on your personal workstation, as this would amount to **provide your user account with root permissions without any `sudo` password prompt nor auditing**).

   See also this page in the official Docker documentation:
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
2. Or, to prepend `sudo` automatically but avoid typing `sudo docker` manually, a good practice consists in adding the following alias in your `~/.bashrc` file (see e.g. [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622105/297058) for details):

   ```sh
   __docker() {
       if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[*]}" =~ "bash-completion" ]]; then
           docker "$@"
       else
           sudo docker "$@"
       fi
   }
   alias docker=__docker
   ```

   Then you can test this by opening a new terminal and typing:

   ```sh
   $ docker run --rm -it debian:10  # asks your password
   $ \docker run --help  # does not ask your password thanks to '\'
   ```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should add user to docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

After you may have to restart Ubuntu